# basin of attraction of z^5+1 (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the basin of attraction of the complex equation z^5+1=0. I have manage to make a big matrix (1000000 elements) with just 6 different values,the 5 roots if the equivalent point converges or something else if diverges. But i cant make a plot mapping each different type of value to a different color. My code so far is

```
    N=1000;
    x=linspace(-5,5,N);
    y=linspace(-5,5,N); 
    A=ones(N,1)*x + 1i*y'*ones(1,N); %A is a 1000x1000 matrix.


    f=@(x) x.^5+1; 
    fp=@(x) 5*x.^4;

    for i=1:20
    A=A-f(A)./fp(A); 
    end
```

pcolor doesn't seem to work with complex argument and if i take abs(A) as argument all different roots converts to same number and i end up with a figure that has just one color, which is strange because some points diverge so i should have 2 colors. Any ideas how can i plot this complex array?

Comment: For reference, Cleve Moler, the original developer of Matlab, did a [great blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/01/18/fractal-global-behavior-of-newtons-method/) recently on this subject, albeit with a fractal twist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the magnitude of the complex numbers, take their phase using `angle`, which will be distinct for each solution, e.g.:

```
h = pcolor(x, y, angle(A));
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```